# javascript :alert NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i get this error message after echo a status message from php to indicate an alert message generated by Jquery and this is my success conditions

```
success : function(e){
        if(e == '0')
        {
            alert("inputs are empty");
        }
        else if(e == '01')
        {
            alert("this input already exists");
        }
        else if(e == '1')
        {
            alert("saved all good");
            clearForm(x);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Unknow Msg : ' + e);
        }
    }
```

it used to work fine then i get this kind of message on firebug

> NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: alert("saved all good");

Comment: possible duplicate of [OnUnload Alert Error "NS\_ERROR\_NOT\_AVAILABLE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517284/onunload-alert-error-ns-error-not-available)

Comment: thats not the same situation plus i dont know if this solution suits me?

Comment: http://www.carlj.ca/2008/06/18/fixing-firefoxs-ns_error_not_available-error-when-using-pagemethods/